# Problems with core-js package when running ng add @angular/fire

Tags: angular, firebase, npm, angularfire2

I am trying to `ng add @angular/fire`  to my project but keep getting this

```
npm WARN deprecated core-js@3.6.5: core-js@<3.23.3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Because of the V8 engine whims, feature detection in old core-js versions could cause a slowdown up to 100x even if nothing is polyfilled. Some versions have web compatibility issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js.
```

Already tried updating the packages with npm update and also installing a different version of the core-js.

I am already using Angular 14.

Any idea on how to solve it?

Thanks a lot in advance!